# How to disable the Javascript "actions/queue/run" on frontend?

Tags: craft3

After upgraded our Craft from 3.3 to 3.4.14 we have noticed that there is a new Javascript on the footer of the homepage (frontend) that runs "index.php?p=actions/queue/run".

We run the tasks via crontab and there is no need for that.

How can we disable it on the frontend?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you set [runQueueAutomatically](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#runqueueautomatically) to `false` in your `config/general.php` file, that will disable that behavior.

Comment: Brad, how is this done in a plugin that returns data? (without setting the runQueueAutomatically to false in the global Craft instance) . I had a custom module pre-3.4 that now returns the queue runner script after its return data.

Comment: The documentation states that it would only inject this in control panel requests, but I see these calls injected into my frontend sites (which, I would like to disable).